# Aligning text close to column

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicol

[image]

The above text is produced by the following command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
  \RequireXeTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec,multicol}
     \newcommand\dn{\catcode`\~=12
       \fontspec[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit]{Sanskrit 2003}}
      \setlength{\columnseprule}{1.5pt}
       \setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}
    \begin{document}
   \title{\fbox{{\dn\Huge lalitaa tri"satii stotram}}\vspace*{-1.8cm}}
     \date{}
      \maketitle
       \begin{flushleft}
        {\dn\Large asya "sriilalitaatri"satii stotra mahaamantrasya | bhagavaan hayagriiva .r.si.h | anu.s.tup chanda.h | "sriilalitaamahaatripurasundarii devataa | ai.m biijam | sau.h "sakti.h | klii.m kiilakam |}
          \begin{multicols}{2}
          {\dn\large kakaararuupaa kalyaa.nii kalyaa.nagu.na"saalinii |\\
            kalyaa.na"sailanilayaa kamaniiyaa kalaavatii ||1||
     kamalaak.sii kalma.saghnii karu.naam.rta saagaraa | \\
     kadambakaananaavaasaa kadamba kusumapriyaa  ||2||
          \end{document}
```

Now my question is the width between the text in the left hand side column and the column seperator  is clearly more than what we see in the right hand side column. How to rectify this.

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll not receive any answer, if you don't add some code that shows how you produced the image.

Comment: @egreg: I have edited accordingly. See if that helps.

Comment: Remove `flushleft`

Comment: @egreg that doesnt help. sorry

Comment: Your code still does not compile: two environments are not closed.  The spacing is caused by `flushleft`, the text in each column is aligned to the left, and the right margin in each column is ragged.

Comment: @AndrewSwann No. I checked. Removing flushleft doesnt help at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not very clear to me, what do you want to achieve. What is the input, few lines with manual line breaks? Longer texts with automatic line breaks? How should the result look like (length of lines, where does the space goes, ...)?
What is the meaning of `|` or `||1||`?

The image can easily be generated with symmetric spaces around the vertical bar.
This can be done by a simple `tabular`. Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\RequireXeTeX
\usepackage{fontspec,multicol}
\newcommand\dn{\catcode`\~=12
\fontspec[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit]{Sanskrit 2003}}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1.5pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}

\usepackage{pbox}
\newcommand*{\tabpbox}{%
  \pbox{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-\tabcolsep-.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{\columnseprule}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{\columnsep}
  \dn\large
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l|l@{}}
    \tabpbox{%
      kakaararuupaa kalyaa.nii kalyaa.nagu.na"saalinii\\
      kalyaa.na"sailanilayaa kamaniiyaa kalaavatii |
    }%
    & 
    \tabpbox{%
      kamalaak.sii kalma.saghnii karu.naam.rta saagaraa\\
      kadambakaananaavaasaa kadamba kusumapriyaa |
    }%
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- `\pbox` is something between a `\parbox` and a `tabular`. The specified width is automatically decreased, if the lines are shorter.
- The font I could found [here](http://www.sanskritweb.net/itrans/sans2003.zip) on the page ["Fonts and Technical Manuals for Itranslator "](http://www.sanskritweb.net/itrans/#SANS2003).

Comment: Thanks. "||" is a means end a shloka in Sanskrit. Thanks for the help. This works.

Answer (score 5):

You're using a `flushleft` environment and give explicit line breaks, so the lines can't be filled.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\RequireXeTeX

\usepackage{fontspec,multicol}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{devanagari}

\setmainfont[Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit]{Devanagari MT} % I don't have Sanskrit 3000

\newcommand\dn{\catcode`\~=12 }
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1.5pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\dn\large kakaararuupaa kalyaa.nii kalyaa.nagu.na"saalinii |
kalyaa.na"sailanilayaa kamaniiyaa kalaavatii ||1||
kamalaak.sii kalma.saghnii karu.naam.rta saagaraa |
kadambakaananaavaasaa kadamba kusumapriyaa  ||2||
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]